# How can i simplify this matricial expression?

Tags: matrices

$$(B^TX)^T-A[(B^{-1}A)^{-1}-B]=0$$

I reach some weird expression like , $X^TB = AA^{-1}*B-AB$ which ends in $X =(I-A)^T$

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures cannot be searched and are not view-able to some. I have [edit]ed your question to reflect this principle.

Comment: What do you find wrong or weird with your result? How would you like it improved?

Answer (score 0):

$$(B^T X)^T-A((B^{-1}A)^{-1}-B)=0$$
$$ X^T B - A(B^{-1}A)^{-1}+A B=0$$
right-multiply both sides by $B^{-1}A$
$$ X^T A - A + A^2=0$$
right-multiply both sides by $A^{-1}$
$$ X^T - I + A=0$$

Comment: The last term before the equal sign has the wrong sign on every line (except the first), e.g. the last line should read $$X^T-I+A=0$$

Comment: @greg I fixed it